# A question about Non Muslims

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sharia, tafseer, fatwa

Non Muslims cannot preach their religion in a Muslim country but a Muslim should be allowed to do so in a non Muslim country. Also if the non Muslim country doesn’t allow Muslims to preach Islam there, Muslims have a right to start a war against the country.
Why is that so?

> Thus what is meant by the passage in Tafsir Uthmani, is that if a country doesn’t allow the propagation of Islam to its inhabitants in a suitable manner or creates hindrances to this, then the Muslim ruler would be justifying in waging Jihad against this country, so that the message of Islam can reach its inhabitants, thus saving them from the Fire of Jahannum. If the Kuffaar allow us to spread Islam peacefully, then we would not wage Jihad against them.

Source: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/17167/i-have-a-question-about-offensive-jihad-does-it-mean-that-we-are-to-attack-even-those-non-muslims-which-dont-do-anything-against-islam-just-because-we-have-to-propagate-islam/

Comment: You must decide which tag to use: [tag:sharia], [tag:fiqh], [tag:halal-haram] are rather synonyms. A distinction is made in [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3141/which-questions-should-be-tagged-sharia-and-or-fiqh), but it is meaningsless to use three tags meaning the same. In my opinion [tag:halal-haram] should never be used with [tag:fiqh] or [tag:sharia].  I don't really know why there is a [tag:fatwa] as we are not a fatwa site a better choice is [tag:fatwa-explanation]. I think your inquiry is already addressed in the not shared part of the fatwa you've linked.

Answer (score 0):

We must acknowledge that we believe out of our faith to Muhammad (p.b.u.h). Out of this belief, it is hard to see people who do not have this faith. From our belief, it is a good deed to make them convert. However, from their belief, it isn't.

Tolerance begins where acceptance is no more possible.
As a Muslim living in a Non-Muslim country I must say that we must be tolerant to those who simply do not share our beliefs. In their views, we are wrong. In particular in my country, we, the Muslim minority get the best support from the Christians who were on our side against anti-Muslim initiatives and lost together with us. They did this in spite of not accepting our prophet (p.b.u.h) for the sake of tolerance.

The same, we ought to admit that we might be in error although our prophet (p.b.u.h) did not consider to be in error and we do not think so, either.
In the present situation, the intolerant behaviour of extremeist and intolerant Islam repels people from our belief.

By force, we won't do good, only generate hypocrites.
The Quranic message is to believe and do good. This is the essential. By this we are in God. By this, people will learn to love and adore God.

Some people think that the verse saying that there's no compulsion in religion is abrogated but it isn't. It is the Wisdom of God Who says that only with a true heart, we can really be submitted and guided by Him. And only if people see us guided by Him doing good, they will be eagerly do alike.

Our religion as well as the Christian religion has been spread out by force; Christianity against the commandment of Jesus, Islam rather following the example of Muhammad (p.b.u.h), when Christians had already started to use force. Still, we have to consider whether the way that seemed to be appropriate in former times is still the way to go today.:

How come that the Jewish prophet Elijah (a.s.) commanded to kill the prophets of baal,  then  Jesus (p.b.u.h) said : Blessed are those who install peace,  and then Muhammad (p.b.u.h) waged war against the polytheistic and then our religion bears the word peace in it?

I do not know the plans of God. But I am personally convinced that the time now is not the time to wage war but to act in love to God the Most High as He commanded us for the times of peace, to believe and do good.

Answer (score 0):

Remember this was in the time of byzintine empire and stuff like that. if they and they didnt allow islam to spread what is then the whole point of islam if its just only gonna stay in mekka? The whole point of the war is spread islam not kill people. Today tho there is no need bc everybody knows islam and can choose to be muslim in every country maybe not north korea or 1 african country. and why doesnt islam allow other religions preach in there country? Bc why would islam allow people to go to hell?